# Running collectstatic on Dokku doesn't copy files

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I created a droplet on Digital Ocean with the Dokku v0.2.3 image, and deployed a django 1.6 project.

I configured it to serve static at /apt/wsgi/static, and noticed this routing works correctly.
My problem is, once I run collectstatic, it reports files were copied, but they're not really there, I ran

```
dokku run myapp ls /apt/wsgi/static
```

on the server and it's empty.

I also tried to copy files manually, run mkdir, and nothing seems to change, my guess is I have no idea how docker actually works.